# How to binarize image using im4java?

Tags: java, image-processing, colors, imagemagick, im4java

I want to turn my color image into B&W. 
Basically, I want to call this ImageMagick command:

```
convert input.png -threshold 80% output.png
```

but using the im4java library. I'm aware of the IMOperation.threshold() method, but I don't know how to write the equivalent of the above command using that method. The method is overloaded:

```
threshold() 

threshold(java.lang.Integer red) 

threshold(java.lang.Integer red, java.lang.Integer green) 

threshold(java.lang.Integer red, java.lang.Integer green, java.lang.Integer blue)

threshold(java.lang.Integer red, java.lang.Integer green, java.lang.Integer blue,
  java.lang.Integer opacity) 

threshold(java.lang.Integer red, java.lang.Integer green, java.lang.Integer blue,
  java.lang.Integer opacity, java.lang.Boolean percent)
```

I tried calling different overloads of the method using different values as arguments, but none of them produce a good result (I usually get either an all white image or an all black image).

So what's the im4java equivalent of "threshold 80%"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to use `blackThreshold`:

```
op.blackThreshold(80.0, true);
```

I'm not sure if it's equivalent to the ImageMagick command I specified, the output seems a bit different, but for all practical purposes it gives me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just in the case you're considering other Java frameworks. Using Marvin Image Processing Framework:

```
MarvinImage image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage('image.jpg');
blackAndWhite(image, 30);
```

**Example of output regarding different BW levels:**

[image]